# Recursion method in Java providing incorrect output

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I am working on a program that will take five numbers from a user then using recursion will provide the user with the sum of those numbers.  My program appeared to be working at first however in my testing I am finding that it is just taking the first number entered by the user and basically multiplying it by five rather than taking the different numbers and finding the sum.  Where am I going wrong with this?  Like I said I am not getting any errors however it is not taking the additional four numbers and calculating the sum of the five numbers.  Any help is always appreciated thank you.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class sumRecusion2 {
        static int i;
        static int N = 5;
        static int[] userNum= new int[N];

        public static int sumUser(int newArray[]) {
            int n = newArray.length;
            if (n == 0)
                return 0;
            int ans = newArray[0]+sumUser(Arrays.copyOf(newArray, n-1));

            return ans;

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
            for(i = 0; i<=userNum.length-1; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
                userNum[i]= scnr.nextInt();
                }}
            catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer without a decimal point!");
                        }
            System.out.println("The sum of your numbers is: "+ sumUser(userNum));

    }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to pass in the array and the index of the element to be summed rather then making a new copy of it each time?

Comment: Your problem is that `Arrays.copyOf(newArray, n-1)` copies the first n-1 elements of the array.  So you get the first of the first 5, then the first of the first 4, then the first of the first 3, ... - so you add the first one, 5 times.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf(newArray, n-1)` should be more like `Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, 1, n)`, otherwise you're just trimming off the last element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.copyOf(newArray, n - 1)` is just trimming of the last element from the array, meaning you are just summing the first element `n` times.

I would consider using `Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, 1, n)` instead, which will make a copy of the array starting from the second element (trimming of the first element)

I, personally, might be tempted to pass in the array AND the index of the element to be summed, which would be more efficient then making `n` number of copies of the array...

```
static int i;
static int N = 5;
static int[] userNum = new int[N];

public static int sumUser(int newArray[], int index) {
    if (index >= newArray.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    int ans = newArray[index] + sumUser(newArray, index + 1);

    return ans;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    userNum = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    System.out.println("The sum of your numbers is: " + sumUser(userNum, 0));

}
```

But, your requirements might differ